# Display save actions for a WFFM form in Sitecore PowerShell

Tags: wffm, powershell-extensions, powershell

I would like with Sitecore Powershell to extract and display the ID(s) of the save action(s) that a WFFM has assigned. Those IDs in fact the ID of items from `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions`.

The field Save Actions from WFFM has the content saved as a xml and I would like to parse it.

Is there a way to do it in Sitecore Powershell ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the script below. Just set the root directory which holds your forms to `$formsRoot` variable.

The script:

- gets all the forms from the root
- gets ids of all the save actions in the system
- creates a regex based on the ids of the actions
- calls the regex on the value of the `Save Actions` field

```bsh
$formsRoot = "/sitecore/content/MYSITE/WffmForms"
$forms = Get-Item master: -Query ($formsRoot + "//*[@@TemplateId='{FFB1DA32-2764-47DB-83B0-95B843546A7E}']");
$availableActionIds = Get-Item master: -Query "/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions//*[@@TemplateId='{E01318E7-CEED-4EA4-B107-1B8FAC3A3DB8}']"| Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID;
$regex = [string]::Join("|", $availableActionIds).Replace("{", "\{").Replace("}", "\}");
$usedSaveActions = $forms | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Save Actions" | Foreach-Object { return [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($_, $regex).Value; }
$usedSaveActions
```

Comment: With some more small adjustments I was able to sued the script you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You could just parse the field contents using the inbuilt PowerShell parsers:

```
[xml]$saveActions = $formItem[Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.FieldIDs.SaveActionsID]
```

That is now in a standard .net `XmlDocument` object, so you can use standard methods to parse that, like `Select-Xml` with `XPath` queries or:

```
$saveActions.node.attribute
```

etc...

Comment: Not that useful in my context, @marek-musielak's suggested helped me better.